# Has anyone had success with GCP OS Patch management

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am now two months into a support ticket with Google support, but since there hasn't been progress I go here to ask as well.

We run a bunch of Windows 2012 based Compute Engines (approx 40 servers) hosting web applications. We have now used OS Patch Management from the Google cloud platform, and basically, for larger updates like Patch Tuesday, it's a lottery if anything gets patched. So of course I now envision having to look for a different solution.

But before doing that, has anyone out there actually used this with success? Or had issues, and found solutions?

To describe the problem, we get servers stuck in "Pending" or "Timeout". We can see that the OS Config server logged absolutely nothing, i.e. basically the Google side never sends a signal to the server. For smaller patches (Defender malware updates) we run them daily usually with no issues at all, the main issue is when Patch Tuesday happens.

Comment: Have you checked this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/best-practices-for-os-patch-management-on-compute-engine).

​

Comment: Hi Sai Chandra, sorry for late reply. Yes it looks great in theory. My problem is practice :)

Answer (score 1):

Please increase the time for patching to 240mins. For windows VMs it takes more time for patching when compared to linux VMs. yes i have also faced similar issues, but when i check the status of the config agent  and restart the agent if required on the Windows VM can solve the problem and if it is timeout you can re-run the job and can get success.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Harsha, thanks for the suggestion. I have increased the timeout, but the VMs never even gets contacted (or the OS Agent has frozen or sth).

Comment: on a second note Harsha, do you "check the status" by running a pre-patch script, or how do you handle that?